# How does the center of a wheel move relative to the world, compared to points on the outside of the wheel?

Tags: geometry

Say you have a bicycle wheel, with radius 1. Every second the wheel moves one revolution. Now a point on the outside of the wheel touches the ground every second, after each revolution, and has moved 2π each revolution (C=π*D). Is this the same case for the center of the wheel, it would seem so right? Each revolution the center of the wheel, even the wheel itself, moves 2π units relative to a fixed external point?

Answer (score 0):

Relative to the ground, the wheel, the point, and the center have all moved $2\pi$ units *forward* after *one revolution*. The center of the wheel has a constant direction, but the point in the outside has changing direction and thus changing forward position as well, but in the end (after an integral number of revolutions) they have moved forwards the same.

Note: When the center moves forward it is moving in the direction of motion of the whole wheel; when the point moves forwards it is moving tangentially to the wheel.